# Display 'No records' in Wp7 Listbox when ItemSource does not have data

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, no-data

How can I show "No records found" when there are no data in itemsource bound to a Listbox.
If I add a new textbox it gives an exception as cannot add data to readonly collection.

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a Grid with a TextBox and the ListBox in front, if the ListBox has content it will hide the TextBox and/or Bind the Visbility to the Count property of your ObervableCollection with a converter.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing this. check the count and hide the listbox if there are zero records and show a textblock with the message.

Answer (score 1):

how are you binding data to the source of the listbox? 
If its by databinding with  a property in its viewmodel, then simply check that property for null or empty . This will serve the purpose.

Providing more info or code you are using can bring in more help.